# powershell remote

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to run this from my local machine (Win7 &  PS v2.0)

```
cls
$sess = Enter-PSSession -ComputerName blmcrmpoc
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -Scriptblock
{
$path = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"
$lastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$oldLogs = Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse -Filter *.log | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $lastWrite}
if ($oldlogs.count -gt 0)
{foreach ($log in $oldLogs)
{$log.Delete()}}}
```

But I get this error.

***Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
cls
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName blmcrmpoc
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -Scriptblock
{
    $path = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"
    $lastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
    $oldLogs = Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse -Filter *.log | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $lastWrite}
    if ($oldlogs.count -gt 0)
    {
        foreach ($log in $oldLogs)
        {
            $log.Delete()
        }
    }
}
```

With `Enter-PSSession` you ENTER a pssession(you start remoting it so you could write the commands directly as if it were the local machine). If you want to use Invoke-Command on a specific session, you create the session using `New-Session` because this creates a session without entering it.

Comment: Are you only recieving the error you posted? What if you run `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName blmcrmpoc` alone in a console. Different error? Are both computers in a domain?

Comment: Both computer are in the same domain and I have full admin rights to both. Yes, I am only recieving the error I posted.

Comment: but as I just asked. Does it work if you use `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName blmcrmpoc` ALONE(don't save to $sess and don't run the rest of the script)? just to enter the session and see if remoting works at all

Answer (score 0):

How to access argument list for scriptblock

ArgumentList is based on use with scriptblock commands, like:

you have to pass arugments for script block..

```
    cls
    $sess = Enter-PSSession -ComputerName blmcrmpoc
    Invoke-Command -Session $sess -Scriptblock
    {
    $path = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles"
    $lastWrite = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
    $oldLogs = Get-ChildItem -path $path -Recurse -Filter *.log | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $lastWrite}
    if ($oldlogs.count -gt 0)
        {
       $xArgvalue= arg[0]
    $yArgvalue= arg[1]
    foreach ($log in $oldLogs)
     {
     $log.Delete()
     }
        }
    } -ArgumentList $x,$y
```

I found on below link [how to pass arguments to script block](http://powershelltutorial.net/home/powershell-questions)