# Powershell - "Copy-item" command in scriptblock of Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, file-copying

I need to copy file from one remote server to other using powershell script.

**What I have tried :-**

While i use following powershell commands it's work fine.(means file copied from one server to other)

[image]

But while i use following script it gives error "cannot find path..." as follows

[image]

Actually, file is exist at that path.

I have tried to refer following stack-overflow already question-answer

- [Error with PowerShell command for copying file to remote server with credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224609/error-with-powershell-command-for-copying-file-to-remote-server-with-credential)
- ['Session' Parameter is null or empty in PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844862/session-parameter-is-null-or-empty-in-powershell-script)
- [powershell remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468278/powershell-remote)
- [Invoke-Command with remote session: Cannot validate argument on parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939872/invoke-command-with-remote-session-cannot-validate-argument-on-parameter)
- [Unable to copy a binary to a remote Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847446/unable-to-copy-a-binary-to-a-remote-azure-vm)
- [PowerShell Command to Copy File on Remote Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719439/powershell-command-to-copy-file-on-remote-machine)

I have also tried to get help using

```
 Get-Help Invoke-Command
```

**Question :-**

1. How can i use "Copy-Item" command inside "Invoke-Command(Scriptblock)" in script(2) to copy file?
2. Is there any better way to achieve this(means best practice)?

Comment: C:\windows.txt exists only on the calling machine?? If your command would’ve succeeded, you would’ve simply copied windows.txt from C:\ to C:\ on the remote host

Comment: @Dough Maurer  yes. for testing purpose now, I have just kept windows.txt at C:\ drive of one machine (source) once command succeed file will copy at other machine(destination) C:\ drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke-Command` has the parameter `-ArgumentList` wich can be used to supply the values of local variables in the remote session. The Problem is: it's just the VALUE of the variable. No file!

**What you can do:**
Use `Get-Content -Raw` on small files to save the contant in a variable. On the target system create a `New-Item` with the `-Value` of that file. However thats not very efficent.

Example:

```
$txt = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\test\oldFile.txt"
$Session = New-PSSession 127.0.0.1
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Param($Txt) New-Item -Path c:\test\newFile.txt -Value $txt }  -ArgumentList $txt 
#Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Result:

```
   Verzeichnis: C:\test    # Sry german OS


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                      PSComputerName           
----                -------------         ------ ----                      --------------           
-a----       03.09.2020     12:23         658033 newFile.txt               127.0.0.1
```

**What you should do:**
I think your use of `Copy-Item -ToSession $Session` is the *right way* to do it. It's litteraly made just for your purpose. The downside is, that the target directory needs to exist. But you need a PSSession for both cmdlets anyway. So you can use `Invoke-Command` with the same PSSession. First Create a PSSession. Use `Invoke-Command` to create you directory. Then use `Copy-Item` to move your file to the right place. Finally you can use `Invoke-Command` to do some finishing steps. And don't forget to `Remove-PSSession` when you are done:

```
$DestinationPath = "C:\test"
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Param($Destination) New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory }  -ArgumentList $DestinationPath
Copy-Item -Path "C:\test\oldFile.txt" -ToSession $Session -Destination "c:\test\newFile.txt"
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { write-host "Do some stuff" }
$Session | Remove-PSSession
```